# node.js socket.io manage mqtt timeout

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mqtt

I got this function:

```
socket.on('ras_mqtt', function(data) {
    if (data == "on") {
        var d = document.getElementById("ras_mqttled");
        d.classList.remove("ledr");
        d.classList.add("ledg");
    } else if (data == "error") {
        var d = document.getElementById("ras_mqttled");
        d.classList.remove("ledg");
        d.classList.add("ledr");
    }
});
```

It works fine, but only when then devices emit a mqtt publish event (every second). What if one event is not received at all, after some seconds ? How to manage an mqtt status if transmit event doesn't emit nothing ?

Comment: Why are you using socker.io rather than using the paho MQTT client to subscribe directly to the broker from the page?

Comment: Because I don't need only client web broker, but also a middleware app. The web app is only the last part of my project

Comment: Nothing stops you having a MQTT client in the backend as well. But still your question needs a lot more detail before we can answer it properly.